# Safely pass Make variable to shell commands

Tags: shell, makefile, escaping, quoting

Consider this Makefile:

```
VAR1=oneword
VAR2=two words
VAR3=three" quoted "words

test:
    printf '>%s< ' "$(VAR1)" "$(VAR2)" "$(VAR3)"
    @echo
```

If I run it, I get

```
$ make test
printf '>%s< ' "oneword" "two words" "three" quoted "words"
>oneword< >two words< >three< >quoted< >words< print
```

but I would like to get the same result as if I ran the following command:

```
$ printf '>%s< ' "oneword" "two words" "three\" quoted \"words"
>oneword< >two words< >three" quoted "words<
```

Assume I cannot change the variables, i.e. I have to change the call to `printf` somehow.

In other words: How do I pass the content of a Make variable to a shell command as one parameter, without any splitting into several or any specific shell effects occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make supports the `export` directive to pass literal content through the environment:

```
VAR1=oneword
VAR2=two words
VAR3=three" quoted "words

export VAR1
export VAR2
export VAR3

test:
        printf '>%s< ' "$$VAR1" "$$VAR2" "$$VAR3"
        echo
```

---

Output:

```
$ make test
printf '>%s< ' "$VAR1" "$VAR2" "$VAR3"
>oneword< >two words< >three" quoted "words< echo
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about `export`. That might be a good alternative, if one does not mind cluttering the environment.

Comment: *nod*. Frankly, I prefer this approach largely for ideological reasons -- passing data out-of-band from code completely removes any potential for escapes -- even though for a POSIX-compliant shell, your answer should be entirely adequate. (I tend to frown a bit on the "sanitize your inputs" part of the Bobby Tables XKCD for the same reasons; a good implementation of bind parameters will put data completely out-of-band from code, making sanitization unnecessary).

Comment: ...of course, the "completely" assumes there isn't a back door for data to become code again, a la Shellshock, but that's a whole different discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It’s not great for readability, but seems to be very reliable.

The idea is to use single quotes on the shell level (`'`), as no variable interpolation or other strange things happen there. Also, it means that the only character that we need to worry about in the contents of the variables are single quotes, and these can be substituted reliably:

```
VAR1=oneword
VAR2=two words
VAR3=three" quoted 'words

test:
    printf '>%s< ' '$(subst ','\\'',$(VAR1))' '$(subst ','\\'',$(VAR2))' '$(subst ','\'',$(VAR3))'
    @echo
```

And now I get

```
$ make test
printf '>%s< ' 'oneword' 'two words' 'three" quoted '\''words'
>oneword< >two words< >three" quoted 'words<
```

Note how make escaped the `'` properly, and how the shell command receives it reliably.